# Angular sub class template accessing a variable defined in a super class

Tags: angular, typescript, oop

My super class component has a variable say `name`. *(a protected variable)*

I want to access it in a sub class html like `{{name}}`.
But it gives following error on **production build**.

```
Property 'name' is protected and only accessible within class 'ABCSuperComponent' and its subclasses
```

When I make the `name` variable public it works fine. But it's not a good **OOP** practice. So any solutions/advices or suggestions on my problem?

Comment: use getter method.

Comment: @ Daniel Segura Pérez could you please explain it (may be post an answer). Actually I'm looking for a proper fix, not a workaround or a hack

Comment: So isn't there any way to use protected because it's be OOP best practice?

Comment: It has to be public because the component's view is external. It references the component the same way external code would access it. So if you think about it, it's still a good OOP practice because external code shouldn't access internal methods. Keep in mind, that the component is create first and the view is later attached. So they are different instances of two different objects.

Answer (score 1):

If you are accessing any property inside your template, then it has to be declared as `public`. Or else it fails during production i. e `ng build --prod`. This may work fine during development.

`ng build --prod` does `aot` compilation. So it should be [AOT](https://angular.io/guide/aot-compiler) compatible

Comment: So isn't there any way to use protected because it's be OOP best practice?

Comment: Well template and component files are considered as two separate files. So to access component variable inside template, it has to be made public. This has nothing to do with inheritance though.

Answer (score 1):

When building for production, angular uses AOT. With this type of build, all variables/methods used in a template must be declared as public in the template's component.

From  (https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/11978)

> With JiT we convert all the code to ES5 and then in runtime we do the bindings. All the visibility modifiers are lost in that process, so it doesn't matter if you say public or private for that.
>
> On the other hand, with AoT, we generate some typescript code for our templates, that will try to access those fields. If they are private, they simply cannot access those properties, hence, we have to put them as public.

This does not change anything that you are using the class in a child class, you'll have the same problem with any component which uses non public property in its template

Comment: So isn't there any way to use protected because it's be OOP best practice?

Comment: Not when using AOT (see quote from github issue)

Answer (score 1):

You can just make the property public and not worry about it.

```
export abstract MyClass {
      public name: string;
}
```

You can define public read access with protected write access.

```
export abstract MyClass {
      private _name: string;

      public get name(): string {
          return _name;
      }

      protected set name(value:string) {
          this._name = value;
      }
}
```

You can define a read access method

```
export abstract MyClass {
      protected name: string;

      public getName(): string {
           return this.name;
      }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

50 reputation to be able to comment????

I've noticed that in some instances AOT allows access to protected properties and methods.

for example

when foo is protected then

`<input [required]="foo">` will not cause an error during aot build

but

`<p>{{foo}}</p>` will cause an error